# See the core data table in Device

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

In my App am using core data to store the data. Now I need to do the core data migration. To check the core data migration done properly I want to see the core data table is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect your device to your computer and open Organizer in Xcode, you can copy the database file from your device and inspect it using your favorite tool.

1. Connect your device to your computer
2. Open Xcode->Organizer
3. From the Devices tab select Applications (under your connected device)
4. At the bottom there is a section called "Data files in sandbox"
5. Click "Download" to copy files to your computer

Comment: I can't find it, most likely because Xcode has changed a lot since your answer. Do you know a way to do this in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 10.2.*

1. Make sure device is connected to the computer.
2. Selected 'Window' tab -> 'Devices and Simulators'
3. Select your application
4. Click on the wheel symbol displayed on the bottom of the device window. A small popup will appear with three options
5. Select 'Download Container...'. And save the app bundle at required location on your computer.
6. goto the downloaded app bundle file in finer and right click on it.
7. Select 'Show Package Contents'
8. Open 'AppData' -> 'Library' -> 'Application Support'. This will list the sqlite database of your application.

Use any sqlite database viewer utility application (e.g. DB Browser for SQLite) to see the content of the database.